# Voltage to segments on 7 segment display?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I am thinking of purchasing an LTS4680 seven segment display for one of my projects.Here is the datasheetdatasheet:http://www.icpdf.com/icpdf_datasheet_7_datasheet/LTS4680AE_pdf_1732299/LTS4680AE_datasheet.html

I understand that it is a common cathode 7 seg display, so ground should be connected to the common cathode pin.What pin is it?I'm not sure but i think it's pin 6 according to the diagram in the datasheet.Also what value of resistors do I need to connect to the anode(+) of each segment.My power supply is 5v at 0.6A(600mA).

Comment: Instead of connecting resistors to each segment(the anode of each segment)can't I just connect the resistor to the common cathode.Would the resistor value be different?Sorry, I am completely new to this stuff.

Comment: if you use a single resistor on the common lead, the brightness of the segments will vary, depending on how many segments are lit.

Comment: Ok so I'll just stick to connecting the resistors to the anode of each segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data sheet, pins 1 and 6 are both connected to the common cathode. The data sheet also specifies a segment drop of 2 volts at a current of 20 ma.  Therefore, you should chose a resistor to drop 3 volts at 20 ma for a 5 volt supply.  That resistance is 150 ohms. You may have to adjust this slightly since the data sheet values are only nominal.  However, there is a maximum specified current of 25 ma per segment which you should be careful to avoid exceeding.

Comment: Can I just connect two 220 ohm resistors to each common cathode pin?Would 220 make the display too dim?

Comment: Disregard my last comment.Can I connect 220 ohm resistors to each anode pin of each segment?

Comment: @zack1544: You should connect one resistor to each anode pin (on a common cathode display).  The exact value to use depends on how bright you want the display - higher value = lower current = dimmer display.  LEDs are not fussy about the current, as long as it doesn't exceed the maximum rated current.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now.So I need to use a resistor of at least 150 ohms, connected to each anode pin of each segment.

Comment: Thank you Peter and Barry, for both your responses.I finally understand what I have to do.